# how to redirect https to new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I redeveloped my company's website and I'm having some issues with redirecting / SSL

Typing or clicking on http://olddomain.org redirects just fine to https://newdomain.com.
However, typing or clicking on the link https://olddomain.org does not redirect to https://newdomain.com and I get this error:

> Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for olddomain.org. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.newdomain.com, newdomain.com

Is there some rewrite conditions I can put in my .htaccess file to fix this? Or is this an issue with the way that I set up the SSL certificate for the new domain?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
 </IfModule>
  <br />
```

and

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?http://olddomain\.org$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or is this an issue with the way that I set up the SSL certificate for the new domain?

Yes, you need a valid SSL cert that covers the *old domain* (as indicated in the browser error... "it uses a certificate that is not valid for olddomain.org").

Without the valid cert the browser cannot connect (securely) to `olddomain.org` so never even sees the redirect directives.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! We still have a valid ssl certificate for our old domain, and a new ssl certificate for our new domain. They are not the same certificate though, so it seems like the browser is trying to validate the old domain with the new certificate

Comment: @sarahm16 In that case it sounds like you have a server config (or perhaps DNS) issue... your server appears to be responding with the wrong SSL cert, or `olddomain.org` is pointing to the wrong server/vHost?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having CloudFlare redirect your old domain to your new domain.  They do a great job of redirecting entire domains using their free service tier.  They even create and manage the security certificate for you so that HTTPS redirects work.

It is a little bit of work to set up.  You have to set the NS records for the domain name to point to cloudflare and tweak several settings within the Cloudflare site.  I have [complete instructions on Webmasters Stack Exchange that you can follow](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/129449#129449).